# Access c# database OleDbException

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I tried writing codes to access database but there was OldDbException error at the line with the bold words. How should I change my words so that there will not be any errors at run time?

```
    private void submitbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        availabilitytabControl.SelectedTab = orderlisttabPage;

        OleDbConnection myAccessConn = myAccessConnection();
        OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

        try
        {
          int i;

            myAccessConn.Open();
            String insert ="insert into Particulars (Title,FirstName,LastName,Nationality,PassportNumber,PhoneNumber) VALUES(";


            for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {
                myAccessCommand.CommandText = insert;
                String title = titlecomboBox.Items[i].ToString();
                String firstname = firstnametextBox.Text;
                String lastname = lastnametextBox.Text;
                String nationality = nationalitycomboBox.Items[i].ToString();
                String passportno = passporttextBox.Text;
                String phoneno = phonenotextBox.Text;

                myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(insert,myAccessConn);
                OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);
                **myAccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();**

            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to retrieve the required data from the DataBase.\n{0}", ex.Message);
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            myAccessConn.Close();
        }


    }
```

Comment: What is the exception message _exactly_?

Comment: You have the insert query incomplete. Probably you need to re-read the rules for an INSERT query

Comment: Add a breakpoint just before `myAccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();` and look at the `myAccessCommand.CommandText`. You'll notice that it's not a valid SQL syntax. And that's the problem. You've set the first half of the INSERT where you define the columns, then you *started* to define the VALUES but you never actually do anything with all those string variables in your `for` loop. Also, general convention is to use `string` for variables and `String` when utilizing the actual class. Such as `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()`. And in the future, include what `ex.Message` says in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you *never* add your values in your `VALUES(..)` part in your query.

My suggestion is;

- Define your parameter in your `VALUES` part
- Add your values with `myAccessCommand.Parameters.Add` in your for loop.
- Execute your query.
- `Clear()` your parameters just before your wanna insert values for next loop.
- Your `OleDbDataAdapter` part is unnecessary since you try to put INSERT statement in it.

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also use `using` statement to dispose your database connections and commands.

```
using(var myAccessConn = myAccessConnection());
using(var myAccessCommand = myAccessConn.CreateCommand())
{
    myAccessCommand.CommandText = @"insert into Particulars (Title,FirstName,LastName,Nationality,PassportNumber,PhoneNumber) 
                                    VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        myAccessCommand.Parameters.Clear();

        myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", titlecomboBox.Items[i].ToString());
        myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", firstnametextBox.Text);
        myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", lastnametextBox.Text);
        myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", nationalitycomboBox.Items[i].ToString());
        myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", passporttextBox.Text);
        myAccessCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", phonenotextBox.Text); 

        myAccessConn.Open();
        myAccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I used `AddWithValue` method as an example but you don't. [This method *may* generate unexpected results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use Add method overloads to specify your parameter type and it's size.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to modify your code like that:

(Let me note that this is only a TEST CODE to check that it solves your problem, you will have to construct your command by using parameter.add() for your code to be safe)

```
private void submitbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    availabilitytabControl.SelectedTab = orderlisttabPage;

    OleDbConnection myAccessConn = myAccessConnection();
    OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand();
    DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

    try
    {
      int i;

        myAccessConn.Open();
        String insert ="insert into Particulars (Title,FirstName,LastName,Nationality,PassportNumber,PhoneNumber) VALUES(";


        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {

            String title = titlecomboBox.Items[i].ToString();
            String firstname = firstnametextBox.Text;
            String lastname = lastnametextBox.Text;
            String nationality = nationalitycomboBox.Items[i].ToString();
            String passportno = passporttextBox.Text;
            String phoneno = phonenotextBox.Text; 
            insert  += "'"+ firstname +"','"+ lastname+"','"+nationality + "','"+ passportno +"','"+ phoneno +"')";


            myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(insert,myAccessConn);
            OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);
            **myAccessCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();**

        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to retrieve the required data from the DataBase.\n{0}", ex.Message);
        return;
    }
    finally
    {
        myAccessConn.Close();
    }
}
```